# Spring 3: Incorrect prioritizing of profile specific property sources

Tags: spring

We are trying to upgrade from Spring 2.7.2 towards Spring 3.

In commit https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/6ec9c432cb2c02840b85fdd8bcd0859eabc0ba46,
Function “ConfigServerConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolverContext, ConfigDataLocation)” was changed:

```
    public List<ConfigServerConfigDataResource> resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolverContext context,
                    ConfigDataLocation location)
                    throws ConfigDataLocationNotFoundException, ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException {
            return resolveProfileSpecific(context, location, null);
    }
```

This leads to the following problem:
Configuration sources that are profile specific become prioritized over ones that are application specific.
This happens because it brings sources for default profile, application specific arrive there as well, and they are added last, despite the fact they arrived also when the profile was specified and were higher prioritized.

Is there any way to receive back the previous behavior?
Or any explanation what was the intention?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question seems better suited to be asked on the project's issues page. If it prioritizes profile-level configurations over application-level configurations, then it is working correctly, as that is the order of precedence in Spring.